# I need to deconvolve the image of a fluorescent bead without the Point Spread Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, deconvolution

I am aware that I could use deconvolution algorithms such as [LUCY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution), [Weiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) and [Blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution) but I am confused as to how to estimate the PSF (point spread function), which is needed for the LUCY and Weiner algorithms. I am currently using the Widefield Florescence Microscopy setup.

I have read in a lot of places around the internet that a fluorescent bead that represents a sub resolution object and therefore a impulse function. While I understand that the OTF (optical transfer function) is represented by the image I am getting, how am I superposed to deconvolve the image I have using the very same image?

Here is an example of the image I am trying to deconvolve:

[image]

I have a program which automatically singles in on the bead and crops the rest of the image. All I need to do is apply deconvolution to this.

My ultimate aim to achieve optical sectioning by deconvolving a bunch of 2D slices I got from a video and representing them with a 3D software.

So can someone please explain what I need to do, either theoretically (or in terms of MATLAB, which would be preferred).

---

**One Possible Solution**

After talking to a few people, I have noticed that EPFL have a [Java resource](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/algorithms/psfgenerator/) that is callable from MATLAB. It's a PSF generator, based on the specifications of your microscope. This generated PSF can be used with the LUCY and Weiner.

---

**Alternative Solution**

I have also found [this](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31945-widefield-fluorescence-microscope-point-spread-function) resource, which is a MATLAB library dedicated to what I am working on right now.

---

[This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/what-are-the-figures-of-merit-performance-measurements-i-can-use-for-deconvolut) (I would love it, if someone attempts to answer this question too) is how I will measure the performance of the deconvolution algorithms. I believe that the ultimate result of my deconvolution will depend on the PSF estimation (EPFL resource or Praveen's algorithm) and the deconvolution algorithm (Blind, LUCY, Weiner etc.). I will post a table of all the results here once this is done.

Comment: Are you using widefield fluorescence microscopy? If not what modality do you use?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I'm using Bright field microscopy. The exact name of the microscopy I've been given was Optical Photon Reassignment Microscopy (OPRA), since I am only responsible for the data. I'm sure it wasn't confocal, but let me find out (does the deconvolution affect the out of focus light?)

Comment: Yes the process of deconvolution is dependent of the light outside the focus, unless it does not carry any useful information and is only noise. I don't have much time now but I'll try to write a thorough answer later :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 It's definitely not Confocal, so I guess it's wide field? For one, the out of focus blur is still a part of the image

Comment: yep that would be widefield

Comment: @Benoit_11 Any update on this answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I have stated within the questions, the key is to create a model of the PSF, using one of the theoretical PSF generators and then inputting both the 3D stack of images and the 3D PSF stack. I have also answered the linked question about the measurement of the performance of the deconvolution algorithm in my particular case, so please do not hesitate to ask me to clear anything.